DataTable with Absolute plugin changed the type of the column, ordering wrong
I am using DataTable to present the information in my table, but at a certain point I needed to add a line at the top, for this in my research I saw that there is the Absolute plugin. After that I was able to leave the specific line at the top, when necessary, using the first column (ID), of which all numbers are integers. However, when using this plugin, check that it transforms the field from INT to STRING, thus ordering the rest of the table incorrectly, as shown below:
ID 8 Fixed, ordering the rest on ID DESC:
Image
ID 8 Fixed, ordering the rest on ID ASC:
Image
Then the result is that is ordering as String, not as Int (Number).
CODE:
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Str__ID = $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrder([
        {
            position: 'top',
            value: '8'
        }
    ]);
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY');
    $('#DT__List').DataTable({
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "columnDefs": [{
            "orderable":    false,
            "targets":      [3]
        },{
            "type":     Str__ID,
            "targets":  [0]
        }],
        "info":             true,
        "fixedHeader":      true,
        "language": {
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending":    ": ativar para classificar a coluna ascendente",
                "sortDescending":   ": ativar para classificar a coluna descendente"
            },
            "buttons": {
                "copy":             "Copiar",
                "copySuccess": {
                    _:              "( %d ) linhas copiadas para a área de transferência!",
                    1:              "( 1 ) linha copiada para a área de transferência!"
                },
                "copyTitle":        "Copiar",
                "csv":              "CSV",
                "excel":            "Excel",
                "pdf":              "PDF",
                "print":            "Imprimir"
            },
            "emptyTable":           "N&atilde;o h&aacute; registro(s)!",
            "info":                 "P&aacute;gina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty":            "N&atilde;o h&aacute; registro(s)!",
            "infoFiltered":         " (Do total de _MAX_ registro(s))",
            "lengthMenu":           "Mostrar _MENU_ registro(s) em cada p&aacute;gina",
            "loadingRecords":       "Carregando&hellip;",
            "paginate": {
                "first":            "Primeira",
                "last":             "&Uacute;ltima",
                "next":             "Pr&oacute;xima",
                "previous":         "Anterior"
            },
            "processing":           "Processando&hellip;",
            "search":               "Pesquisar:",
            "searchPlaceholder":    "Pesquisar…",
            "zeroRecords":          "Opsss, n&atilde;o encontramos nada atrav&eacute;s da sua pesquisa!"
        },
        "order":        [[0,"desc"]],
        "ordering":     true,
        "pageLength":   10,
        "paging":       true,
        "select":       true
    });
});

I even tried to change the column by code, but without success:
{
    "type":     "num",
    "targets":  [0]
}

Anyone solved this error?
I made a big search, but nobody asked that...

I received the solution on another forum, we have a function called absoluteOrderNumber:
DataTable.absoluteOrderNumber = function (values) {
    var conf = _setup(values);
    DataTable.ext.type.order[conf.name + '-asc'] = function (a, b) {
        return conf.asc(a, b, true);
    };
    DataTable.ext.type.order[conf.name + '-desc'] = function (a, b) {
        return conf.desc(a, b, true);
    };
    return conf.name;
};

